# SED Add white space from variable

Tags: regex, sed, line, whitespace

Trying to use the following to add white space to end of file based on a variable

```
sed 's/$/&\( \)\{'"$DIFF"'\}/'
```

However, this just adds the a literal ( ){3} to the end of the lines.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The replacement string is not a regular expression; `\( \)\{3\}` in the replacement string means literally `( ){3}`. You want to make a string of `$DIFF` spaces; for this purpose you can use `printf %${DIFF}s` (just so, with no arguments).

Putting it all together

```
sed 's/$/'"$(printf %${DIFF}s)"'/'
#            ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
#            That's $DIFF spaces
```

Comment: I had come to the conclusion that the replacement string doesn't use regular expressions after many attempts at changing formatting, thanks for confirming, Looking at your example I understand most of what is going on, but what does the % indicate?

Comment: Ah, I found a site that explains more about printf. Your example is setting a string of characters with a minimum length of $DIFF, which puts out empty space where there are no characters entered. Correct?

Comment: @TurboAAA: Yes. For example %5s is a string of (at least) 5 characters; with no arguments it's 5 spaces.